# how to execute a query in magento when order is successfull

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento-1.7

Im new to magento,
I need to execute a query to insert a flag into orders table of magento when an order is successful (i.e returned from payment page), Ive found the front end files, but not sure where to place the code to execute this simple query, Im not comfortable with folder structure of magento.

Im using `magento 1.7` currently

Please help me if you know where is the controller file to achieve this, if you can give me the file paths and class names it will be much helpful for me to uderstand this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the event for `OrderAfterSave`, In observer file, you will get the last order id by using that you could insert flag.

Here is the link to tutorial. Hope this will help

http://blog.decryptweb.com/event-observer-magento/

Answer (score 0):

You should use an Observer for this as it is the cleanest method as you do not have to rewrite any core files.

See http://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-7/ for a full list of observers in Magento 1.7

See http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method for more information about using observers.

If you want to observer the order success action I would use `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action` there are many others regarding orders, something like `checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after` as it will give you access to the order object which you will not have to reinitialize.